# Apply Where Clause if Condition Met

Tags: sql

I want to apply a where clause if a local variable is not null. eg.

```
declare @controlName nvarchar(250);

    SELECT 
        *
    FROM
    (
    SELECT  TOP (100) PERCENT 
        dbo.Blah.PageName, 
        dbo.BlahBlah.ControlName, 
        dbo.BlahBlah.ControlText, 
        'en' AS FriedEgg
    FROM         
        dbo.WebPageText INNER JOIN
        dbo.Blah ON dbo.BlahBlah.WebPageID = dbo.Blah.WebPageID

     if @controlName is not null

         WHERE dbo.BlahBlah.ControlName = IN(@controlName, not null)
```

So if the control name  variable is not null, apply the where clause

Comment: What database and which version thereof are you working with?

Comment: Can't you; `where @controlName is null or dbo.BlahBlah.ControlName = @controlName`

Comment: Is the @ControlName variable a LIST of name?  If so, you need to think differently and use a function to *split* the list into a table of values.  `IN (1,2,3,4)` is fundamentally different from `IN (@myList)`

Answer (score 4):

Simplest answer...

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT 
  dbo.Blah.PageName, 
  dbo.BlahBlah.ControlName, 
  dbo.BlahBlah.ControlText, 
  'en' AS FriedEgg
FROM         
  dbo.WebPageText
INNER JOIN
  dbo.Blah
    ON dbo.BlahBlah.WebPageID = dbo.Blah.WebPageID
WHERE
  dbo.BlahBlah.ControlName = @controlName
  OR @controlName IS NULL
```

Comment: One addition just put the `@controlName IS NULL` at left of `OR`. This makes sense with the condition in the question

Comment: @Oybek - `(x OR y) == (y OR x)` I don't understand why you support the order needs to be different?

Comment: this always return every result

Comment: @user880954 - If @controlName is NULL then every result is returned.  If @controlName is a value, then `OR @controlName IS NULL` is false - so only records where `dbo.BlahBlah.ControlName = @controlName` is true will be returned.  It won't *always* return every row.

Answer (score 2):

If this is for SQL Server, you could try to use the `ISNULL` function:

```
DECLARE @controlName nvarchar(250);

SELECT 
    dbo.Blah.PageName, 
    dbo.BlahBlah.ControlName, 
    dbo.BlahBlah.ControlText, 
    'en' AS FriedEgg
FROM         
    dbo.WebPageText 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Blah ON dbo.BlahBlah.WebPageID = dbo.Blah.WebPageID
WHERE 
    dbo.BlahBlah.ControlName = ISNULL(@controlName, dbo.BlahBlah.ControlName)
```

With this, if `@controlName` is `NOT NULL`, then your `WHERE` clause is:

```
WHERE 
    dbo.BlahBlah.ControlName = @controlName
```

but if @controlName **is** `NULL`, then you get

```
WHERE 
    dbo.BlahBlah.ControlName = dbo.BlahBlah.ControlName
```

and that's always true, so you're not restricting your result set

Answer (score 0):

```
...
WHERE dbo.BlahBlah.ControlName = COALESCE(@controlName, dbo.BlahBlah.ControlNmae)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the fillowing:

```
      WHERE @controlName is null OR rest_of_the_condition
```

if `@controlName` is null, it will evaluate to true and `WHERE` clause is true irrespective of the `rest_of_the_condition`. Where as if `@controlName` is not null the `rest_of_the_condition` in `WHERE` clause will come to effect.

Comment: If you're using an `AND`, this won't work.  Also, short-circuit logic doesn't work the same way in SQL (because the optimizer is free to reorder the clauses); look at alex's comment on the original post for a better version.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting your IF-test in the WHERE clause?

```
WHERE @controlName is not NULL AND dbo.BlahBlah.ControlName = IN(@controlName, not null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Could use T-SQL:

```
declare @controlName nvarchar(250);
IF(@controlName IS NULL)
BEGIN
    SELECT 
    *
    FROM
    (
    SELECT  TOP (100) PERCENT 
       dbo.Blah.PageName, 
       dbo.BlahBlah.ControlName, 
       dbo.BlahBlah.ControlText, 
       'en' AS FriedEgg
    FROM         
    dbo.WebPageText INNER JOIN
    dbo.Blah ON dbo.BlahBlah.WebPageID = dbo.Blah.WebPageID
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT 
    *
    FROM
    (
    SELECT  TOP (100) PERCENT 
        dbo.Blah.PageName, 
        dbo.BlahBlah.ControlName, 
        dbo.BlahBlah.ControlText, 
        'en' AS FriedEgg
    FROM         
    dbo.WebPageText INNER JOIN
    dbo.Blah ON dbo.BlahBlah.WebPageID = dbo.Blah.WebPageID
    WHERE dbo.BlahBlah.ControlName = @ControlName

END
```